# How to make Magento Main Catgories Menu With Completely Custom HTML

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.4

I am making a Magento theme using a CSS framework and need to completely rewrite the HTML structure for most of the blocks. I am stuck on the main categories menu. I googled and found out that I have to override the `top.phtml` in `catalog/navigation` folder, but that does not give me complete control over the HTML. I need this to implement a custom menu dropdown system.

This is the component that is rendered with:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

From what I have read about Magento, it gives you complete control over the HTML of the site. I can't believe that it will not for the main navigation of the site, such an important component that developers get creative with.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: check this link [Getting and Using Categories and Sub Categories](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/getting_and_using_categories_and_subcategories)

Answer (score 2):

This unfortunate state of affairs arises from the non-templated, embedded HTML in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` class's `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` method.

You can do one of the following:

- Overwrite this method via Magento's class rewriting mechanism (note that it is used recursively)
- Re-implement this functionality anew - even extending from the original class but adding a new rendering method and template.

HTH